# What is the maximum limit of thread for the following PHP MySQLi init?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Site wide is using the following single statement to call for DB connection, Understand that the code is included by all the other php files. Seems like it will be reaching a limit, because i check the RDS side is having single connection for multiple users. How can i find out the maximum limit of threads? or max sharing pool?

```
unset($db1);
$db1 = new MySQLi($db_url,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name,$db_port);
$db1->query("set names utf8");
```

Comment: Why are you including this in each file? Why not connect once and reuse the connection? What is the reason?

Comment: What do you mean maximum limit of threads? PHP always executes in a single thread. There is no connection pool. Everytime you create a new object, a new connection is estabilished

Comment: That'd be an uninteresting finding because the theoretical limit depends on the server OS and effective limit surely depends on hardware, configuration and user limits, and I also bet MySQL Server is shared by more applications than yours. If you're trying to solve a specific problem, you should probably ask about that.

Comment: @Ron because PHP closes the connection when the execution is finished?

Comment: For a whole PHP project, it is enough to init a new `$db1 = new mysqli(....)` and then in ALL of the project to reuse this `$db1` ... there is no need to `unset` it or re-initiate it again and again attaching it to any new PHP file ,in which you would `include` or `require` the database.php where you have ONCE initiated the connection...

Answer (score -3):

A better option would be to change those 3 settings in your config.

```
mysql> help set names;
Name: 'SET NAMES'
Description:
Syntax:
SET NAMES {'charset_name'
    [COLLATE 'collation_name'] | DEFAULT}

This statement sets the three session system variables
character_set_client, character_set_connection, and
character_set_results to the given character set. Setting
character_set_connection to charset_name also sets collation_connection
to the default collation for charset_name. See
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html.

The optional COLLATE clause may be used to specify a collation
explicitly. If given, the collation must one of the permitted
collations for charset_name.

charset_name and collation_name may be quoted or unquoted.

The default mapping can be restored by using a value of DEFAULT. The
default depends on the server configuration.

Some character sets cannot be used as the client character set.
Attempting to use them with SET NAMES produces an error. See
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html#charset
-connection-impermissible-client-charset.

URL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-names.html
```